# Array only printing last integer

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

Been trying to figure this out for awhile now and cannot figure it out, It is only printing the last number in the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class proj81 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arry = new int[11];
        System.out.print("You will be asked to enter a set of 10 integers.\n");
        int i = 1;
        int count = 0;
                while(count<=9) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
                    arry[i] = reader.nextInt();
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.print(arry[i]);
                }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does, the print statement is outside of your while loop. Try this:

```
while(count <= 9) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
    arry[count] = reader.nextInt();
    count++;
    System.out.print(arry[count]);
}
```

I have replaced `i` with `count`, because `i` is just a constant, so you're not filling the array.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny you're right (if that's what you meant), `i` is never incremented. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems:

1. i should be initialized to 0, not 1.
2. The array should be size to 10 if you're holding 10 numbers.
3. If you want to output after each addition, then move the output inside the loop.
4. If you want to just output the entire array, then change your output to:
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arry));